# Algorithm for generating integer partitions up to a certain maximum length

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, integer-partitions

I'm looking for a fast algorithm for generating all the partitions of an integer up to a certain maximum length; ideally, I don't want to have to generate *all* of them and then discard the ones that are too long, as this will take around 5 times longer in my case.

Specifically, given $L = N(N+1)$, I need to generate all the partitions of $L$ that have at most $N$ parts. I can't seem to find any algorithms that'll do this directly; all I've found that seems relevant is [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02241987) paper, which I unfortunately can't seem to access via my institution's subscription. It [apparently](https://web.archive.org/web/20141013222856/http://www.site.uottawa.ca:80/%7Eivan/F49-int-part.pdf)<sup>1</sup> documents an algorithm that generates the partitions of each individual length, which could presumably be easily adapted to my needs.

Does anyone know of any such algorithms?

<sup>1</sup>*Zoghbi, Antoine; Stojmenović, Ivan*, [**Fast algorithms for generating integer partitions**](https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00207169808804755), Int. J. Comput. Math. 70, No. 2, 319-332 (1998). [ZBL0918.68040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0918.68040), [MR1712501](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1712501). [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141013222856/https://www.site.uottawa.ca/%7Eivan/F49-int-part.pdf)

Comment: Is 1+2+3 different from 3+2+1?

Comment: No; partitions are unordered.

Comment: Knuth's [AoCP Volume 4](http://cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/), under the 'Generating all partitions' section, page 2, [Algorithm H](http://cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc3b.pdf)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it recursively. Let $f(n, maxcount, maxval)$ return the list of partitions of $n$ containing no more than $maxcount$ parts and in which each part is no more than $maxval$.

If $n = 0$ you return a single list containing the empty partition.

If $n > maxcount * maxval$ you return the empty list.

If $n = maxcount * maxval$ you return a single list consisting of the obvious solution.

Otherwise you make a series of recursive calls to $f(n - x, maxcount - 1, x)$.

Comment: I'm actually already using this approach, but it generates compositions rather than partitions (i.e. they're ordered), which isn't what I want in this case. Obviously for large $n$ this makes the number of results somewhat unmanageable! Thanks, though!

Comment: @Will: Are you sure? I think that should work fine; that's what `maxval` is for.

Comment: This algorithm can generate each partition with their elements ordered from greatest to least - it's just a matter of prepending x to the partitions obtained from the recursive call. Or it can generate them ordered from least to greatest - postpend.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad! My existing implementation was lacking the maximum value logic present in yours. This indeed works as required now, thanks :)

Comment: P.S. I would vote this up as well as accepting but I did so last night and then undid it until I'd implemented it to make sure it works, and now it's been locked. I guess this is a bug in the voting system?

Comment: @Will, I think it's to stop abuse of the system. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in using an actual implementation, you could go for the `integer_partitions(n[, length])` in [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/). More details can be found [here](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_38.html).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a very simple modification to the ruleAsc algorithm at http://jeromekelleher.net/category/combinatorics.html

```
 def ruleAscLen(n, l):
    a = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]
    k = 1
    a[0] = 0
    a[1] = n
    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        y = a[k] - 1
        k -= 1
        while x <= y and k < l - 1:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        a[k] = x + y
        yield a[:k + 1]
```

This generates all partitions of n into at most l parts (changing your notation around a bit). The algorithm is constant amortised time, so the time spent per partition is constant, on average.

Answer (score 0):

This article about Gray codes includes partitions. The idea behind a Gray code is to enumerate a cyclic sequence of some combinatorial collection of objects so that the "distance" between consecutive items in the list are "close."   http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0196677489900072
Savage also has other survey articles about Gray codes that include partitions. http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/s/u/a_survey_of_combinatorial_gray_codes__213043.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an algorithm that generates all partitions of $L$ into $N$ parts in the multiplicity representation, Knuth calls it the "part-count form". I only found algorithm Z from A. Zoghbi's 1993 thesis http://dx.doi.org/10.20381/ruor-11312 to output partitions in this form but it generates all partitions of $L$. I coded it up as `partition(L)` in C++ and added a slight modification to only generate partitions into $N$ parts, `partition(L, N)`. I put the code with both functions on github as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fredRos/1be056502742dba0753828e7852f9986). Both have the same update to go from one partition to the next and just need a different initialization.

Zogbi claims that the multiplicity form is faster, his algorithm Z is just a transform of algorithm H mentioned in [Knuth's TAOCP 4](http://cs.utsa.edu/%7Ewagner/knuth/fasc3b.pdf) to partition $L$ into $N$ parts in standard representation but Z was at least 2x faster than H in their tests, albeit on 1993 hardware :)

Comment: Knuth usually abbreviates "The Art of Computer Programming" to TAOCP.