# Drawing colored balls

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sack with $15$ *red balls*, $15$ *blue balls*, $15$ *green balls* and $15$ *yellow balls* (balls of the same color are indistingishable).

In how many ways can I take $30$ balls from the sack?

$\\ $

I tried using $(\binom{4}{30})$, [*combination with repetition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition), but that ignores the restriction of having at most $15$ balls of the same color.

I thought about using a [*permutation with repetition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition), but I don't know how to then not take into account the order.

Comment: $\binom{4}{30}$ doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: It's not $\binom{4} {30}$ ,but  ($\binom{4} {30}$), which is combinations with repetition. You can find info about it in the provided link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking for an integer partition of $30$ with at most four summands, each at most $15$, i.e.
$$\#\{(a,b,c,d)\mid a+b+c+d = 30;~~ a,b,c,d\ge 0;~~ a,b,c,d\le 15\}$$
The first two of the conditions can be solved using the stars-and-bars method,
$$\#\{(a,b,c,d)\mid a+b+c+d = 30;~~ a,b,c,d \ge 0\} = \binom{33}3$$
From these you have to subtract those where at least one summand exceeds $15$. If one summand exceeds $15$, no other can because $30-16 = 14 \le 15$, so these are disjoint. The four sets all have the same cardinality, namely that of
$$\#\{(a,b,c,d) \mid a+b+c+d=30;~~ b,c,d \ge 0;~~ a \ge 16\} \\
=\#\{(a,b,c,d) \mid a+b+c+d=14;~~ a,b,c,d\ge 0\} = \binom{17}3$$

So the final answer is
$$\binom{33}3 - 4\cdot \binom{17}3 = 2736$$

Comment: Very elegant! Perhaps you'd like to apply your partition-wrangling skills to [this recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281770/207316). :)

Answer (score 1):

AlexR has given a combinatorial solution.  Here is one with a recursion which produces the same answer.

If $f(n,m)$ is the number of ways of drawing $n$ balls from the first $m$ colours with no more than $15$ of each colour then $f(n,0)=0$ except $f(0,0)=1$ and $$f(n,m)=\sum_{j=0}^{15} f(n-j,m-1).$$  This can be translated into a generating function where you want the coefficient of $x^{30}$  in the expansion of $$\left(1 + x+ x^2+ \cdots + x^{15}\right)^4 = \left(\frac{1-x^{16}}{1-x\,\,\,}\right)^4$$ or you could just do the arithmetic of the recursion giving the following table:

```
n/m 0   1   2   3   4
-   -   -   --  --- ----            
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   1   2   3   4
2   0   1   3   6   10
3   0   1   4   10  20
4   0   1   5   15  35
5   0   1   6   21  56
6   0   1   7   28  84
7   0   1   8   36  120
8   0   1   9   45  165
9   0   1   10  55  220
10  0   1   11  66  286
11  0   1   12  78  364
12  0   1   13  91  455
13  0   1   14  105 560
14  0   1   15  120 680
15  0   1   16  136 816
16  0   0   15  150 965
17  0   0   14  162 1124
18  0   0   13  172 1290
19  0   0   12  180 1460
20  0   0   11  186 1631
21  0   0   10  190 1800
22  0   0   9   192 1964
23  0   0   8   192 2120
24  0   0   7   190 2265
25  0   0   6   186 2396
26  0   0   5   180 2510
27  0   0   4   172 2604
28  0   0   3   162 2675
29  0   0   2   150 2720
30  0   0   1   136 2736
```

so the same answer as AlexR