# How many 5 letter different words can be formed using the letters AAASSSBB

Tags: permutations, combinations

I saw that these sort of questions have been asked before, but not exactly this kind of problem: creating 5 DIFFERENT words, not just all possible combinations.

The words don't need to have any meanings.

I'd appreciate an explanation in addition to the solution.

Comment: If you tried anything you should show your work.

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296924/how-many-2-letter-words-can-you-get-from-aabcccddef)

Comment: `grep -E '^[asb]{5}$' /usr/share/dict/words`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Letters}  & \text{Calculation} & \text{# Possibilities}\\
\hline\\
AAASS &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{3} & 10 \\\\
AAASB &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{3} \cdot 2 & 20\\\\
AAABB &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{3} & 10\\\\
AASSS &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{2} & 10\\\\
AASSB &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2} & 30\\\\
AASBB &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{2} \cdot 3 & 30\\\\
ASSSB &  5\cdot \displaystyle\binom{4}{3} & 20\\\\
ASSBB &  5\cdot \displaystyle\binom{4}{2} & 30\\\\
SSSBB &  \displaystyle\binom{5}{3} & 10\\\\
\end{array}
$$

---

This gives a total of $$\boxed{170}$$

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use generating functions. Find the coefficient of $x^5$ in:

$$f(x) = 5! \cdot (1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3!)^2 \cdot (1+x + x^2/2!) $$

In general, the number of length-$n$ words that can be achieved from an alphabet of $k$ distinct letters containing $b_i$ counts of letter $i$ (over all $1 \leq i \leq k$), is found by taking the coefficient of $x^n$ of $f(x)$ where:

$$f(x) = n!\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{b_i}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)$$

One nice thing about this approach (in my opinion) is that it is generalizable and easily adjustable, and doesn't require individual case-counting.

Comment: How did you derive this formula and why is coefficient of $x^5$ result?

Comment: @johnnobody Coefficient of $x^5$ because you are choosing $5$ letters.

Comment: OK, so if would have 4 letter words it would be at $x^4$? But how do you calculate this function?

Comment: Yes, it would be $4!$ instead of $5!$ and you'd be looking at the coefficient of $x^4$ instead of $x^5$. 

There are $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ letters that are selected, but if we pick $j$ letters of any particular type ($A$, $S$, or $B$), we must divide by $j!$ to render them indistinguishable amongst themselves. Generating functions in general are useful for counting up the number of ways to arrive at a particular outcome.

Comment: Answered a similar question a long while back using this same approach, another example can be seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1890120/97648

Answer (score 4):

There are words that use only two different letters, and there are words that use all three.

$2$ letters:

It must be three of one and two of another.

$3$ $A$'s, $2$ $S$'s

$3$ $A$'s, $2$ $B$'s

$3$ $S$'s, $2$ $A$'s

$3$ $S$'s, $2$ $B$'s

In any case, the number of words is $\binom53=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=\frac{5\cdot4}{2\cdot1}=10$

With four choices of letter-pairs, that gives us $40$ words.

---

$3$ letters:

The possible formats here are $3$ of one letter, and $1$ each of the other two, or $1$ of one letter, and $2$ each of the other two.

$3,1,1$:

The letter occurring $3$ times could be $A$ or $S$, so there are two lists of letters to work with. In either case, you can form $20$ words. That's $\binom53=10$ choices for where the three copies of one letter go, and $2$ ways to fill the remaining blanks.

That's another $40$ words.

$2,2,1$:

Now any of the three letters can be the one that occurs once. Given a letter-list, We have $5$ ways to choose where the lone letter goes, and $\binom42=6$ ways to place the remaining ones. We have $3\cdot 5\cdot 6=90$

---

Finally, $40+40+90=170$

Comment: OK good, we meet having approached from opposite ends. :-)

Comment: I also got the same answer. Definitely $170$ :)

Comment: thank you i finally understand it :)

Answer (score 3):

If we were just forming length-$5$ words that consisted of the three letters $A,S,B$, there would be $3^5$ options - each letter position has $3$ independent choices.

We need to restrict that total to reflect the restrictions on count of each letter. In this case you cannot have a word that breaks constraint on $2$ letters at the same time.

How many of those unconstrained words have $4$ or $5$ copies of $A$? Clearly the answer is $1+2\binom 5 4 = 11$:
$AAAAA$
$BAAAA$
$SAAAA$
$ABAAA$
etc.

and similarly for $S$. Then for $B$-constraint-breaking words, there are those $11$ plus $\binom 5 3(2+2) = 40$. So we end with $3^5-73=170$ valid options.

Comment: If it were possible to have multiple constraints simultaneously broken, this could be extended using an inclusion-exclusion approach.

Comment: I agree that the number of words with $4$ or $5$ As is $$2\binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5} = 2 \cdot 5 + 1 = 10 + 1 = 11$$ and that there are the same number of words with $4$ or $5$ Ss.  However, the number of words with $3$, $4$, or $5$s is $$2^2\binom{5}{3} + 2\binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5} = 4 \cdot 10 + 2 \cdot 5 + 1 = 40 + 10 + 1 = 51$$ which yields a total of $11 + 11 + 51 = 73$ prohibited words.

Comment: Sure, that's what I got too in my answer... I did consider switching the $(2+2)$ to $2^2$ later on. Perhaps you missed that I acknowledge the $11$ options for $4$ or $5$ $B$s and only calculated the $3$ $B$s options explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

$${5!\over 3!2!0!}+ {5!\over 3!1!1!}+{5!\over 3!0!2!}+{5!\over 2!3!0!}+{5!\over 2!2!1!}+{5!\over 2!1!2!}+{5!\over 1!3!1!}+{5!\over 1!2!2!}+{5!\over 0!3!2!} =$$

$$=4{5!\over 3!2!}+ 2{5!\over 3!}+3{5!\over 2!2!} = 170$$

Comment: In case it is unclear how this solution arose, it is likely via [casework](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Casework) on the number of letters of each type. Once the number of letters of each type is decided, the number of words in each case is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients). EDIT: This method is effective for small problems like this one. However, it does not scale very well, and would be very difficult to pull off if the number of letters was larger, and/or the number of types of letters was larger.

Comment: Somebody down voted just now. Why?

Comment: Maybe it was the lack of explanation, of where those terms came from? I don't know; I upvoted. I like how you broke it down.

Comment: Thanks Tony, is it not exactly the same as Zubin Mukerjee did?

Comment: Well, both of you, as well as I, took the same approach and got the same correct answer. Zubin annotated the lines in his table with letters, I wrote a lot of prose about what I was doing, and you laid out each term with consistent format. Diff'rent strokes for diff'rent folks, I guess.