Find the smallest constant $C$ with given condition.
We have $100$ coins with a total value of $50$ (something, the currency really doesn't matter), such that the value of each coin does not exceed $1$, but it is a positive real number. Determine the smallest $C > 0$ such that it is possible to divide the coins into two piles of $50$ coins each, whose values do not differ by more than $C$.
I found this problem while reviewing my old Olympiad combinatorics course,  unfortunately I can't solve it now. I believe it should be an algorithm of some sort, but I just can't find it. I have no idea how to start, although I thought about the pigeonhole principle to find the minimal number of coins of some value, but that led me nowhere...

What currency is this and what are the denominations in that currency ? This is a global forum !

Oh, OK, if you insist I'll add the currency. I don't think it's important for the problem, but OK.

Is the smallest possible coin one euro cent?

No, that's why I didn't want to add the currency. It can be ANY positive real number.

For a target, if there are $51$ coins of value $\frac {50}{51}$ and $49$ coins of value $0$ we would have $C=\frac {50}{51}$.  Can you beat that?  The same limit comes from $49$ coins of $1$ and $51$ coins of $\frac 1{51}$, which avoids the worry that maybe coins can't be worth $0$

"It can be ANY positive real number".  Ok, you should [edit] that info explicitly into the question. I suspect this question would be easier if we were working with limited integer cent value coins.

This related question might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281770/207316

@RossMillikan I don't think we get to choose the values of any of the coins. Our algorithm has to divide any collection of 100 coins into two almost equal value piles.

I agree.  This is the best (most uneven collection) I could find.  The correct $C$ has to be at least this large.  It remains to prove that any other collection can be divided at least this well.

Let $n=50$ and $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. In the example from Ross Millikan's comment the difference between the total values of the piles is always at least $\frac n{n+1}$. We show that this bound is tight, that is we can always provide the difference between the total values of the piles to be at most $\frac n{n+1}$ as follows.
Let the coins are ordered such that their values $v_1,\dots,v_{2n}$ do not increase. Let $\Delta=\max \{v_{2i-1}-v_{2i}:i\in [n]\}$. Suppose that $\Delta=v_{2i-1}-v_{2i}$ for some $i\in [n]$. Put $a=\frac 1{2i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{2i-1} v_j$ and $b=\frac 1{2n-2i+1}\sum_{j=2i}^{2n} v_j$. Then $\Delta\le a-b$. For each $j\in [n]$ put $v'_j=a$, if $j\le 2i-1$, and $v'_j=b$, otherwise. Then $v'_1,\dots,v'_{2n}$ are also the values of feasible coins ordered in a nondecreasing order. Moreover, we can increase $a$ and decrease $b$ keeping the total value $(2i-1)a+(2n-2i+1)b=n$, achieving either $a=1$ or $b=0$. Then $a-b$ equals $\frac{n}{2n-2i+1}$ in the first case and $\frac{n}{2i-1}$ in the second case.
Since $a-b\le 1$ and $n$ is even, $\frac n{n+1}\ge a-b\ge \Delta$.
Now place the coins with the odd numbers into the first pile and the coins with the even numbers into the second pile. Let Difference be the total value of the first pile minus the total value of the second pile. Suppose that Difference is $D$. Now we do $n$ consecutive swaps such that for any natural $i\le n$ at $i$th turn we swap the coins $c_{2i-1}$ and $c_{2i}$. After each turn Difference changes by at most $2\Delta$ and finally it becomes $-D$. Therefore at some step the absolute value of Difference is less than $\Delta\le \frac n{n+1}$.
