# Find all integer partitions

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

For example, to find the partitions of 7, I wouldn't need to like do trial and error kind of thing and have to constantly check whether I have already got such a partition, miss out on some combinations and all that of confusion. So any simple method to do this without much head-scratching?

I'm not talking about the number of partitions btw, just the partitions themselves like 1+1+1, 2+1, 3.

Comment: See also [Algorithm for generating integer partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18659/algorithm-for-generating-integer-partitions).

Comment: A simple computer call, e.g., `IntegerPartitions[59]` in *Mathematica*.